# Round specific columns in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rounding

I have a multidimensional numpy array, some columns are floats, others are strings. I want to round the float columns to 3 decimal places. I cant use `np.round()` as that only seems to work on numpy arrays that are made up of the same type (i.e. they are all floats). A snippet of my code can be seen below:

```
cat = '/home/myname/catalogue.csv'
cat = Table.read(cat, format="ascii")

ID1 = np.array(cat['ID_1'])
ID1 = ID1.astype(str)

ID2 = np.array(cat['ID_2'])
ID2 = ID2.astype(str)

mag = np.array(cat['magnitude'])
mag = mag.astype(float)

semi_major_axis = np.array(cat['SMA'])
semi_major_axis = semi_major_axis.astype(float)

semi_minor_axis = np.array(cat['sma'])
semi_minor_axis = semi_minor_axis.astype(float)

position_angle = np.array(cat['position_angle'])
position_angle = position_angle.astype(float)

match = (ID1, ID2, mag, (semi_minor_axis/semi_major_axis), position_angle)
match = np.stack(match, axis=1)
```

Is there any way to round specifically the magnitude, axis ratios and the position angle to 3 decimal places?

Comment: Do you want a string with three digits after the decimal point? Or do you want to round the internal binary representation to the nearest thou?

Comment: The strings themselves are fine its the floats I would like to round to three digits

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, you just have to round the arrays before you stack them:

```
cat = '/home/myname/catalogue.csv'
cat = Table.read(cat, format="ascii")

ID1 = np.array(cat['ID_1'])
ID1 = ID1.astype(str)

ID2 = np.array(cat['ID_2'])
ID2 = ID2.astype(str)

mag = np.array(cat['magnitude'])
mag = mag.astype(float)
mag = np.round(mag, decimals = 3)

semi_major_axis = np.array(cat['SMA'])
semi_major_axis = semi_major_axis.astype(float)

semi_minor_axis = np.array(cat['sma'])
semi_minor_axis = semi_minor_axis.astype(float)

axis_ratio = semi_minor_axis/semi_major_axis
axis_ratio = axis_ratio.astype(float)
axis_ratio = np.round(axis_ratio, decimals = 3)

position_angle = np.array(cat['position_angle'])
position_angle = position_angle.astype(float)
position_angle = np.round(position_angle, decimals = 3 )

match = (ID1, ID2, mag, axis_ratio, position_angle)
match = np.stack(match, axis=1)
```